# Using Jquery to change passord input type, but site will not apply remembered password

Tags: jquery, forms, passwords

Here's the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user_pass').one('focus',function() {
        $('#userpasscont').html('<input type="password" value="" id="user_pass" class="text" name="pwd">');
        $('#user_pass').focus();
    })
    $('#user_login').one('focus',function() {
        $('#user_login').val('');
    })
});
```

Here's the form:

```
<p><input type="text" id="user_login" class="text" value="Username" name="log"></p>
<span id="userpasscont"> <input type="text" value="Password" id="user_pass" class="text" name="pwd"></span>
```

It works great except I can't figure how to pass a saved password into it.

Comment: Are you trying to display the password for some reason?

Comment: Where is the saved password coming from? I don't see anything that looks like persisted data in the code above.

Comment: I meant the password from the browser's saved password list

Answer (score 0):

Web server technologies shouldn't be passing around saved passwords.  Even if it passes a value for the saved password, you shouldn't be able to see it.  Best bet, it to just leave the boxes blank and let the user type something in if they want.

If a user submits new information then you know what's going on if they submit those fields.

Comment: I agree, however, it was a request made, so I am trying to make it work.

Comment: May want to try renaming thefield then.  There are going to be querks with trying this as password is generally some type of reserved word (washes from logs, doesn't come back to screen on edit, etc.  Rename it to something else, and it should make your job easier.  Also, usually if I have a request like this come in I explain the security implications and they are normally ok with an acceptable alternate.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are replacing the input after the DOM is finished loading and thats the reason why it doesn't offer to remember the password:

```
$('#userpasscont').html('<input type="password" value="" id="user_pass" class="text" name="pwd">');
```

You can change this line of code by this one:

```
if($('#user_pass').attr('value')='Password'){$('#user_pass').attr('value', '')}
```

Comment: I don't see how that will help.  I have to initially have the field set to a normal text field so the word "password" is visible, then change it to a password field.

Also, browsers will not let me change the type of field if it is a password field.